# blocking commands as non-root

Tags: centos, command, non-root-user

This is a very specific request, I am afraid.
I am a non-root user at a CentOS Linux 7 machine. The admin team is normally very helpful but there is zero response for that case, unfortunately.

So I have no root power here and I would like to block/restrict some commands for **myself**: *links*, *links2*, *lynx*. Don't ask me why, please, treat this a weird challenge, perhaps?

Is there any way to achieve that being a non-root user?

Comment: Probably not in a way you couldn't also undo yourself.

Comment: Yes! Kind of a "trick" I did was overriding built-in command by alias. But, unfortunately, in process of searching for a solution I also learnt that '\command' over-override the alias I put in the .bashrc. I am not power-user by any means, running my own small desktop with Mint and using CentOS machine for basic but time-consuming calculations. I won't be able to "undo" restrictions anyway (probably).

Comment: If your aim is, as I suspect, not to spend too much time browsing the Web, the best way you can accomplish this is through self-discipline.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a directory in your home, create some files with the
names of programs you want to restrict and prepend it to your
$PATH. For example:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

Create ~/bin/links with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo you are not allowed to use links
```

and make it executable. Prepend ~/bin to $PATH:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now when you call links:

```
$ links
you are not allowed to use links
```

It won't be possible to bypass it with `\` as it would be if alias was used:

```
$ \links
you are not allowed to use links
```

Note that links is still there in the $PATH:

```
$ type -a links
links is /home/ja/bin/links
links is /usr/bin/links
```

And that nothing can stop you or other processes from calling the
real links binary using an absolute path /usr/bin/links.